# Three.Js v66 and transform controls

Tags: three.js

Three.js is up to v66 and the Gizmo transform controls seemed to have stopped working.
See a demo here:

```
This is the basic code

var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

var control = new THREE.TransformControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
control.addEventListener( 'change', render );
control.attach( mesh );
scene.add( control.gizmo );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hq2Dx/5/

There is no apparent error but they do not appear. I've tried debugging but cannot isolate the issue. Anyone else managed to get it working?

Cheers

Comment: Here is the old examples on three. http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_transform.html

Comment: What is "old" about the example you linked to?

Comment: Hi West, sorry this was the old example I meant to post. It appears that example I sent though has the newest version :)  http://aleksandarrodic.com/p/three/examples/misc_controls_transform.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code.. it  will do the trick.. check this fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/Hq2Dx/7/

```
var control = new THREE.TransformControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
control.addEventListener( 'change', render );
control.attach( mesh );
scene.add( control);
```